# Scroll Bar in JFrame Not Showing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add a horizontal scroll bar to my JFrame that essentially contains a bunch of JButtons. In my code, you can see that I've added 19 green JButtons called "Ground", as well as several other buttons. The last few clearly go off-screen. What I want is to implement a scroll bar so that I can view all the buttons. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the JScrollPane scroll bar working. It shows up, but doesn't actually scroll.

I'd appreciate some feedback!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class World {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Just defining my own colour hues
        Color blue = new Color(77, 121, 255);
        Color green = new Color(0, 255, 0);
        Color grey = new Color(166, 166, 166);
        Color red = new Color(255, 102, 102);

        // Create the JFrame
        JFrame f = new JFrame("World");

        // Creating the JButtons. They're added to the JFrame at the end of the code.
        JButton object0 = new JButton("Object");
        object0.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
        object0.setBackground(red);

        JButton object1 = new JButton("Object");
        object1.setBounds(80, 80, 80, 80);
        object1.setBackground(red);     

        // This just automatically adds the "Ground" buttons to the frame, as they are many of them.
        ArrayList<JButton> groundList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
            groundList.add(new JButton("Ground"));
        }
        JButton temp;
        int x = 80;
        for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
            temp = groundList.get(i);
            temp.setBounds(x, 0, 80, 80);
            temp.setBackground(green);
            f.add(temp);
            x = x + 80;
        }

        JButton wall = new JButton("Wall");
        wall.setBounds(80, 160, 80, 80);
        wall.setBackground(grey);

        JButton avatar = new JButton("Avatar");
        avatar.setBounds(0, 80, 80, 80);
        avatar.setBackground(blue);

        f.add(object0);
        f.add(object1);
        f.add(wall);
        f.add(avatar);      

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setVisible(true);
        f.add(scroll);  // This adds the scroll bars but doesn't actually make them work.   
        f.setSize(800, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

Comment: `JScrollPane` is a complicate component and you really should start by reading the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) and [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) to bet a better idea of how it works and how you work with it.  `JScrollPane` contains a `JViewportView`, this maintains a reference to the base component which is to be considered for layout, onto this, you add you components and then let the layout manager system do the rest

Comment: ... which means, you won't get away with `setBounds`, you're going to have to make an effort to understand how layout managers work

Comment: I've added code sample based on your implementation, and horizontal scroll is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to drop the scrollable content inside the scroll bar instance. 
Thus you need first to create a JPanel and add all your buttons to the panel, then create the JScrollPane with the panel passed to its constructor.

Adding UI components directly to the JFrame is not a good practice.

Try running this and inspecting changes, it should work:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class World {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Just defining my own colour hues
        Color blue = new Color(77, 121, 255);
        Color green = new Color(0, 255, 0);
        Color grey = new Color(166, 166, 166);
        Color red = new Color(255, 102, 102);

        // Create the JFrame
        JFrame f = new JFrame("World");
        //button will be added to this panel
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

        // Creating the JButtons. They're added to the JFrame at the end of the code.
        JButton object0 = new JButton("Object");
        object0.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
        object0.setBackground(red);

        JButton object1 = new JButton("Object");
        object1.setBounds(80, 80, 80, 80);
        object1.setBackground(red);     

        // This just automatically adds the "Ground" buttons to the frame, as they are many of them.
        ArrayList<JButton> groundList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
            groundList.add(new JButton("Ground"));
        }
        JButton temp;
        int x = 80;
        for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
            temp = groundList.get(i);
            temp.setBounds(x, 0, 80, 80);
            temp.setBackground(green);
            myPanel.add(temp);
            x = x + 80;
        }

        JButton wall = new JButton("Wall");
        wall.setBounds(80, 160, 80, 80);
        wall.setBackground(grey);

        JButton avatar = new JButton("Avatar");
        avatar.setBounds(0, 80, 80, 80);
        avatar.setBackground(blue);

        myPanel.add(object0);
        myPanel.add(object1);
        myPanel.add(wall);
        myPanel.add(avatar);      

        //notice how the panel is dropped inside the scroll pane
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(myPanel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setVisible(true);
        //f.add(scroll);  // This adds the scroll bars but doesn't actually make them work. 

        //finally add the scroll to frame's content pane .. which is more proper than adding to frame directly
        f.getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(800, 200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        f.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

[image]

**However**

If you consider setting initial preferred size to your panel, you'll get all buttons line wrapped and you will not need to scroll horizontall:

```
myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 200));
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, @Cortex; thank you very much. A quick question, though: if I want to place the buttons precisely in the order in which they were (which is why I used the setBounds() method on the buttons), how can I keep the original layout (or rather, the original order, I should say) and still have the scroll bars?

Comment: Glad I helped, the x and y of `setBounds` won't be effective in this case because of the FlowLayout. Buttons will appear in the order in which they were added to to the panel. So change the location/order of `myPanel.add(..);`. Also add this `temp.setText(Integer.toString(i));` inside the green button for loop so you see the order of addition. In general, placement is covered under [Layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) topics and I encourage you to spend time learning it.